# How create custom query with several params ReactiveCrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have User, for example:

```
public class User {
long id;
String name
}
```

I need to create custom query

"select * from smthEnt where title like %username% and id = SmthParams "

where:  smthEnt = table, username = User.Name, SmthParams = parametr like Integer

I try:

```
@Query("select * from shops where title like %:#title% and user_id = :#{#user.id}")
Flux<Shop> findByPersonalTitleContains(String title, User user);
```

No parameter specified for [#title] in query [select * from shops where title like %:#title% and user_id = :**synthetic_0**]

How to create query right?

```
@Table("shops")
@Data
public class Shop extends BaseEntity {
  ...
  private Long userId;
    private String title;
  ....
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your `Shops` entity (you use it in your Query: `...from shops...`)

Comment: posted table entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query("select * from shops where title like concat('%',:title,'%') and user_id = :userId")
Flux<Shop> findByPersonalTitleContains(String title, Long userId);
```

Please note that the second argument in `findByPersonalTitleContains` has changed from `User user` to `Long userId`.

You can read more in: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#r2dbc.repositories.queries

For a list of user ids (`List<Long> userIds`) try the following IN query:

```
@Query("select * from shops where title like concat('%',:title,'%') and user_id in (:userIds)")
Flux<Shop> findByPersonalTitleContains(String title, List<Long> userIds);
```

Comment: executeMany; bad SQL grammar [select * from shops where title like %:title% and user_id = :userId]; nested exception is io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlBadGrammarException: [42601] syntax error at or near "%"

Comment: Yes, it works. But what if I need a lot of user parameters?